# Facebook Checkin API By Place ID Get All Users List

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-checkins

I want to get all the Users of Check-In at my Place. But Facebook provides only those Users which are available in my Friends List.

I have tried with the below link.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=location&&place={My Place ID}&access_token={My Access Token}
```

Can any one suggest Is it feasible to get All the users (not only which are in my Friends) list on My Place by Check-In API ?

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: Read this article, maybe it would help you:
[People Search using Facebook Graph API – Find Users through Name or Email](http://www.codinglogs.com/blog/web-development/facebook/people-search-using-facebook-graph-api-find-users-through-name-or-email)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This is restricted. Let's say I've checked in at your place but I've restricted my posts to be visible to only friends, so you won't be allowed to see it. This is because all checkins are considered at simple Posts since Checkin object is deprecated in favor of a Post with a location attached.

Answer (score 0):

Try do this using FQL of Facebook,
Check if you are using the App Credentials and look what your place needs about permission of the users.

Look at this link of Facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/checkin/